# Null when filtering Many-to-Many relationship with JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I have an issue with filtering in JHipster.

Here is my (relevant) **jhipster-jdl.jh** file :

```
entity Exercise {
    name String required
}

entity Difficulty {
    name String required
}

entity Language {
    name String required
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Exercise{language(name)} to Language
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Exercise{difficulty} to Difficulty
}

filter Exercise
```

I generated the Springboot service with JHipster and did not change anything.

*Let's say I have an exercise called "test" with difficulty "easy" and languages "spanish" and "dutch".*

When I query the `GET exercises` endpoint with the filter `name.equals=test` :

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice/api/exercises?nameId.equals=test
```

I get this answer :

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1000,
        "difficulty" : {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "easy"
        },
        "languages" : null,
        "name" : "test"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the issue is that **I don't have direct access to the languages linked to my exercise.**

Note that the `difficulty` field has no issue because it is a many-to-one relationship.

**The database is not the source of these issues**, because if I query the `GET exercises/{id}` endpoint with the exercise's id :

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice/api/exercises/1000
```

I get the right result :

```
{
    "id" : 1000,
    "difficulty" : {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "easy"
    },
    "languages" : [
        {
            "id" : 200,
            "name" : "spanish"
        },
        {
            "id" : 205,
            "name" : "dutch"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "test"
}
```

Now let's try to query the `GET exercises` endpoint with the filter `languageId.greaterOrEqualThan=200` (for the sake of the example) :

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice/api/exercises?languageId.greaterOrEqualThan=200
```

Then the response will be :

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1000,
        "difficulty" : {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "easy"
        },
        "languages" : null,
        "name" : "test"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1000,
        "difficulty" : {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "easy"
        },
        "languages" : null,
        "name" : "test"
    }
]
```

**Notice that the exercise comes out twice** (or `n` times if it has `n` languages meeting the constraint, I checked), which is problematic.

**I feel like something in the JHipster generator is broken, but it seems unlikely because I did not find anybody talking about this quite crippling issue.**

Did I do something wrong when generating my JHipster project ? Or is it a true issue ?

Please feel free to ask for any other piece of code, I'm not sure what could be relevant. Thanks.

Note : I noticed the exercise endpoint filters for the `languages` field use the singular (e.g. `language.equals`), I don't know if this is normal for a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I know it's been quite a time, but did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm sorry @LinaBasuni, this is too old for me to remember anything, sadly. But if I had found a satisfying solution for this problem back then, I would definitely have posted an answer here. I probably ended up using a radically different approach or using a different technology. Good luck !

Comment: I recognized that the relation can only be fetched from the place where the @JoinTable exists, it contradicts with the idea of bidirectional!! I found someone who is dividing the M-M relation into 2 M-One relations to fix this issue. Please if anyone have more details let's spread the knowledge.